# Error al imprimir un registro tipo text en php usando pdo e informix

Tags: php, pdo, informix

Amigos por favor necesito ayuda,
Hasta ayer, no tenía ni un problema imprimiendo registros que tengo en mi base informix desde php usando pdo.
Pero ayer me tope con un registro tipo (text), y me imprime (resource id #)
Como les dije cualquier otro tipo de texto no tengo problema.
A continuación les pondré de como llamo a una tabla con la siguiente estructura:
PRUEBA

```
codigo              int
clave               char(12)
registro            varchar(10)
contenido           text
```

Código php

```
 $ls_query = ("select * from PRUEBA");
    $ls_res_usr = $ls_conn->query($ls_query);                           
    $ls_result = $ls_res_usr->fetchAll();
    foreach($ls_result AS $ls_res_usr)
    {
        $id_cod= trim($ls_res_usr[0]);
        $id_cla= trim($ls_res_usr[1]);
        $id_reg= trim($ls_res_usr[2]);
        $id_con= trim($ls_res_usr[3]);
    echo $id_cod . "-".$id_cla . "-".$id_reg . "-".$id_con;
    }
    unset ($ls_res_usr);
```

Y el resultado que obtengo es este:

```
1-1AB-La Paz-(Resource id #2)
4-3FG-La Paz-(Resource id #3)
5-1AB-Santa Cruz-(Resource id #4)
18-5TY-Oruro-(Resource id #5)
24-3wE-Sucre-(Resource id #6)
```

...

Y en realidad deberia mostrarme un texto 
Por favor su ayuda.

Comment: ya la edité, gracias por la observación

Comment: Si dentro del `foreach`, si ejecutas un `var_dump($ls_res_usr)`, que resultados obtienes? (con uno solo alcanza)

Comment: Me sale asi `/opt/aplicaciones/apache/htdocs/htdocs/firma/pruebasdavo/pruebasdavoA/pruebasdavo/prueba/validado.php:34:resource(2, stream)

-

/opt/aplicaciones/apache/htdocs/htdocs/firma/pruebasdavo/pruebasdavoA/pruebasdavo/prueba/validado.php:34:resource(3, stream)

-

/opt/aplicaciones/apache/htdocs/htdocs/firma/pruebasdavo/pruebasdavoA/pruebasdavo/prueba/validado.php:34:resource(4, stream)

-

/opt/aplicaciones/apache/htdocs/htdocs/firma/pruebasdavo/pruebasdavoA/pruebasdavo/prueba/validado.php:34:resource(5, stream)`

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación:

> [PDO::query](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.query.php): Una buena característica de `PDO::query()` es que permite iterar sobre el conjunto de filas devueltos por una ejecución de una sentencia SELECT con éxito.
>
> Aunque esta función está documentada solamente teniendo un único parámetro, se pueden pasar argumentos adicionales a esta función. Éstos serán tratados como si se llamase a [`PDOStatement::setFetchMode()`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php) con el objeto de la sentencia resultante.

Intenta hacer lo así:

```
$ls_query = "select * from PRUEBA";
foreach($cona->query($ls_query, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) AS $ls_res_usr) {

    $id_cod= trim($ls_res_usr['codigo']);
    $id_cla= trim($ls_res_usr['clave']);
    $id_reg= trim($ls_res_usr['registro']);
    $id_con= trim($ls_res_usr['contenido']);
    echo $id_cod . "-".$id_cla . "-".$id_reg . "-".$id_con;
}
unset ($ls_res_usr);
```

// UPDATE

Para una consulta que se necesite ejecutar en múltiples ocasiones, se obtendrá una mejor rendimiento si se prepara un objeto `PDOStatement` usando [PDO::prepare()](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php)

```
$stmt = $cona->prepare("select * from PRUEBA");
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($rows as $row) {

    $id_cod= trim($row['codigo']);
    $id_cla= trim($row['clave']);
    $id_reg= trim($row['registro']);
    $id_con= trim($row['contenido']);
    echo $id_cod . "-".$id_cla . "-".$id_reg . "-".$id_con;
}
```

Comment: Intentando así, no me devuelve nada, ni error, me devuelve vacío.

Comment: el mismo resultado. no me devuelve nada.

Comment: Si hay registros, es un texto largo. Pienso que es que se maneja de otra manera el tipo de dato TEXT. Gracias de todas formas.

Answer (score 0):

Logré mostrar solo un registro, ahora el tema es aplicar el foreach.

```
$sentencia = $cona->prepare("select * from PRUEBA where clave = '1AB' ");
$sentencia->execute();
$sentencia->bindColumn(1, $tipo, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//$sentencia->bindColumn(2, $lob, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
echo ($tipo);
```

Y si obtengo el texto que deseo.

Comment: Veo que aquí estas usando `$cona` en lugar de `$ls_conn`, ¿acaso en la pregunta el nombre esta mal? He restablecido mi respuesta modificando el nombre de la variable de conexión.